# Craft password encryption

Tags: password

When I reset my password with the same password I used before. 
I checked the MySQL database the old encrypted password is different from new encrypted password.

Do you guys know why?

Answer (score 7):

That's because Craft follows the standard procedure of [hashing passwords with what's called a "salt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) as a security measure.

Think about it this way - if a password were hashed without a salt, *every instance of the same password would result in the same hashed value*.

Example:

Suppose there are two users, Foo and Bar. They both choose `password123` as their password. When hashed without a salt, their passwords would look the same after hashing, which is a security flaw.

We can see this by testing it with any hash algorithm:

(I'm using md5 here for readability because it gives a shorter result - do not actually use md5 for anything secure)

`password123` becomes `482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38`, and - without using a salt - would be stored that way for every user with the password `password123`.

The implication here is that the system is now vulnerable to a variety of attacks, like Lookup Tables and Rainbow Tables, which depend upon every instance of a password yielding the same hash.

Enter Salts. Salts are psuedo-random strings attached to the user's password prior to being hashed and stored.

In our Foo and Bar example, that would look something like this:

Foo chooses `password123`. The system generates a psuedo-random "salt" of `pg7n6yVBzWJbaxfF`, *combines them* into `pg7n6yVBzWJbaxfFpassword123`, and then hashes that result to get `d026a6847c743e23195cf37db2a66ae9`. In addition, Foo's generated salt is stored in the table, so that it can be used to test login attempts.

Bar does the same, but the system generates `Am6g4n0JEFdE1poH` as his salt. When combined with `password123` and hashed, it then yields a different result: `5e7b0bb4842ee8315105a62922c32894`.

Both users have the same password, but the final hashed result now has no traceable relationship to the original password in either case. If a malicious party were to try and search for `password123` by scanning the database for its hashed equivalent (in our example `482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e3`), it wouldn't find anything.

The same principle applies to resetting your password - even if you choose the same password, that new instance of the password is re-salted, re-hashed, and stored as something distinct.

Comment: Sam, do you know if Craft passwords also have an application-wide "pepper" added? This would be an added layer of security for when the MySQL data was breached (such as via SQL injection) but without access to the PHP code.